# OpenGL + CUDA interop - image not displaying in window

Tags: opencv, opengl, cuda, interop

**Background**: I read an image from disk using OpenCV, passed it to the GPU using CUDA, and now, I am trying to get OpenGL to render the image.

I am not using GLUT here because I compile my code and get 32-bit Windows to create a new window, inside which I will render the image. Now, I flipped the OpenCV image and got OpenGL to render the image nicely when I simply passed `flipped.data` to the `glTexImage2D()` function. However, the same image is not being rendered when I use CUDA + OpenGL.

My actual images are bigger than the current one. I am using the OpenGL pixel buffer object, and the OpenGL texture to render the image. Utilizing the texture allows me to specify the part of the image I want to display. My grayscale image has dimensions `w1024`x`h256`, and it has an 8-bit depth (unsigned char/GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE).

**Question**: I can't quite figure out what is going wrong in my code. I tried to carefully follow the CUDA C programming guide, and register/map the CUDA resource with the PBO and the texture as well as with the actual input data. Since my input image data comes from OpenCV, I simply copied `flipped`'s data into the device pointer `dev_inp`. I (correctly?) mapped the `dev_inp` to the CUDA resource using `cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer()` as well. Yet, the window does not display anything, and remains black. There are no viewport changes, and the coordinates that I specify at `glBegin().. glEnd()` are correct as they properly map `flipped`'s data to the texture.

**Am I missing something else here? Am I mapping the CUDA resource incorrectly to the PBO or the device pointer?**

**OpenGL + CUDA interop portion**: This portion is specifically only the CUDA + OpenGL interoperation in my code. The function `DrawOpenGLScene()` is called from the `WindProc()` method.

```
void DrawOpenGLScene()
{

    initCUDADevice(); 

    Mat image, flipped;
    image = imread("K:/Ultrasound experiment images/PA_160.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   // Read the file from disk

    if(!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;


    }

    cv::flip(image, flipped, 0);

    imshow("flip", image);  // displays output

    //cout << "depth: " << flipped.depth() << endl;

    // ===================================================================================
    // opengl setup

    // first, the context was created 
    // now, clear the window with the rendering context
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // ====================================================================================
    // generate the pixel buffer object (PBO)

    // Generate a buffer ID called a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object)
    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
    // Make this the current UNPACK buffer (OpenGL is state-based)
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    // Allocate data for the buffer. 4-channel 8-bit image
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned char) * flipped.rows * flipped.cols, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    //gpuErrchk(cudaGLRegisterBufferObject( pbo ));
    gpuErrchk(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_resource, pbo, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone)); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // create the texture object 

    // enable 2D texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // bind the texture     
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    //glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // put flipped.data at the end, and it'll work for normal texturing
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,  image.cols, image.rows,  0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    // put tex at the end, and it'll work for normal texturing
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // ====================================================================================
    // copy data from openCV 

    unsigned char *dev_inp; 

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_inp, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols) );
    //cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)dev_inp, pbo);

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) );

    size_t size; // = sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols; 
    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dev_inp, &size, cuda_resource) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(dev_inp, flipped.data, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    //cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo);
    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) ); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // bind pbo and texture to render data now 

    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, flipped.cols, flipped.rows, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glEnd();


    glFlush();  // force rendering to happen 

    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

**Entire code**:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void DrawOpenGLScene(void);
HGLRC SetUpOpenGLContext(HWND hWnd);

GLuint tex; 
GLuint pbo;
struct cudaGraphicsResource *cuda_resource;


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

{    

    static char szClassName[] = "Myclass";
    static char szTitle[]="A Simple Win32 API OpenGL Program";
    WNDCLASS wc; 
    MSG      msg;  
    HWND     hWnd;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL; 
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject (BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    if (!RegisterClass (&wc))
        return 0;

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szClassName, szTitle, 
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |
                        // NEED THESE for OpenGL calls to work!
            WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
                            0, 0, 1024, 256,
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow( hWnd );
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    return(msg.wParam); 

}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg,
                     WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    HDC hDC;
    static HGLRC hRC; // Note this is STATIC!
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // Select a pixel format and create a rendering context
        hRC = SetUpOpenGLContext(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        // Draw the scene
        // Get a DC, make RC current & associate it with this DC
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
        DrawOpenGLScene();  // Draw 
        // We're done with the RC, so deselect it
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;       

    case WM_DESTROY:
        //cudaGLUnregisterBufferObject(pbo);     
        cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(cuda_resource); 

        // Clean up and terminate
        wglDeleteContext(hRC);

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

            default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return (0);
}

//*******************************************************
//  SetUpOpenGL sets the pixel format and a rendering
//  context then returns the RC
//*******************************************************

HGLRC SetUpOpenGLContext(HWND hWnd)
{
    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
        sizeof (PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), // strcut size 
        1,                              // Version number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |    // Flags, draw to a window,
            PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL, // use OpenGL
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,          // RGBA pixel values
        24,                     // 24-bit color
        0, 0, 0,                // RGB bits & shift sizes.
        0, 0, 0,                // Don't care about them
        0, 0,                   // No alpha buffer info
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,          // No accumulation buffer
        32,                     // 32-bit depth buffer
        0,                      // No stencil buffer
        0,                      // No auxiliary buffers
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,         // Layer type
        0,                      // Reserved (must be 0)
        0,                      // No layer mask
        0,                      // No visible mask
        0                       // No damage mask
    };

    int nMyPixelFormatID;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    nMyPixelFormatID = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC, nMyPixelFormatID, &pfd);
    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    return hRC;
}

//***********************************************************
//  initCUDADevice uses CUDA commands to initiate the CUDA
//  enabled graphics card. This is prior to resource mapping,
//  and rendering.
//***********************************************************

void initCUDADevice() { 

    gpuErrchk(cudaGLSetGLDevice( cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId() ));    

}

//******************************************************** 
//  DrawOpenGLScene uses OpenGL commands to draw the scene
//  This is where we put the OpenGL drawing commands
//********************************************************

void DrawOpenGLScene()
{

    initCUDADevice(); 

    Mat image, flipped;
    image = imread("K:/Ultrasound experiment images/PA_160.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   // Read the file from disk

    if(!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;


    }

    cv::flip(image, flipped, 0);

    imshow("flip", image);  // displays output

    //cout << "depth: " << flipped.depth() << endl;

    // ===================================================================================
    // opengl setup

    // first, the context was created 
    // now, clear the window with the rendering context
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // ====================================================================================
    // generate the pixel buffer object (PBO)

    // Generate a buffer ID called a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object)
    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
    // Make this the current UNPACK buffer (OpenGL is state-based)
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    // Allocate data for the buffer. 4-channel 8-bit image
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned char) * flipped.rows * flipped.cols, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    //gpuErrchk(cudaGLRegisterBufferObject( pbo ));
    gpuErrchk(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_resource, pbo, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone)); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // create the texture object 

    // enable 2D texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // bind the texture     
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    //glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // put flipped.data at the end, and it'll work for normal texturing
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,  image.cols, image.rows,  0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    // put tex at the end, and it'll work for normal texturing
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // ====================================================================================
    // copy data from openCV 

    unsigned char *dev_inp; 

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_inp, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols) );
    //cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)dev_inp, pbo);

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) );

    size_t size; // = sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols; 
    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dev_inp, &size, cuda_resource) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(dev_inp, flipped.data, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    //cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo);
    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) ); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // bind pbo and texture to render data now 

    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, flipped.cols, flipped.rows, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glEnd();


    glFlush();  // force rendering to happen 

    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else runs into the same problem, this thread can serve to help them. 
I solved my problem by changing only a couple of calls in `DrawOpenGLScene()`.

It turns out that `cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer()` returns a pointer to and derived from the OpenGL PBO, and places that pointer in `dev_inp`. It internally allocates `size = sizeof(unsigned char) * flipped.rows * flipped.cols` memory for the `dev_inp` based on the previously established calls to `glBufferData()` and `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer()`.

Once this is done, the memory that I had previously allocated using `cudaMalloc()` now ceases to exist because it is overwritten by the call to `cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer()` that places the pointer in `dev_inp`. Removing the `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaFree()` allowed the program to run as originally intended.

In order to deallocate the memory, one should deallocate the PBO as OpenGL is the "owner" of the memory, and CUDA just shares access to the memory owned by OpenGL.

The modified `DrawOpenGLScene()` routine is pasted below:

```
#define GET_PROC_ADDRESS( str ) wglGetProcAddress( str )

PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC    glBindBuffer     = NULL;
PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC glDeleteBuffers  = NULL;
PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC    glGenBuffers     = NULL;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC    glBufferData     = NULL;

void initCUDADevice() { 

    gpuErrchk(cudaGLSetGLDevice( cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId() ));    

}    

//******************************************************** 
//  DrawOpenGLScene uses OpenGL commands to draw the scene
//  This is where we put the OpenGL drawing commands
//********************************************************

void DrawOpenGLScene()
{

    // Clear Color and Depth Buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();

    // ====================================================================================
    // initiate GPU by setting it correctly 
    initCUDADevice(); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // read the image that needs to be textured 

    Mat image, flipped;
    image = imread("K:/OCT experiment images/PA_175.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   // Read the file from disk

    if(!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;


    }

    cv::flip(image, flipped, 0);

    imshow("OpenCV - image", image);    // displays output

    // ====================================================================================
    // allocate the PBO, texture, and CUDA resource

    glBindBuffer    = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBindBuffer");
    glDeleteBuffers = (PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glDeleteBuffers");
    glGenBuffers    = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glGenBuffers");
    glBufferData    = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC)GET_PROC_ADDRESS("glBufferData");

    // ====================================================================================
    // generate the pixel buffer object (PBO)

    // Generate a buffer ID called a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object)
    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);

    // Make this the current UNPACK buffer (OpenGL is state-based)
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);

    // Allocate data for the buffer. 4-channel 8-bit image
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned char) * flipped.rows * flipped.cols, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);

    gpuErrchk(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_resource, pbo, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone)); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // create the texture object 

    // enable 2D texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // generate and bind the texture    
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // put flipped.data at the end for cpu rendering 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE,  image.cols, image.rows,  0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    // put tex at the end for cpu rendering 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    // ====================================================================================
    // copy OpenCV flipped image data into the device pointer

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    unsigned char *dev_inp; 

    //gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_inp, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) );

    size_t size; 
    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&dev_inp, &size, cuda_resource) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(dev_inp, flipped.data, sizeof(unsigned char)*flipped.rows*flipped.cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_resource, 0) ); 

    // ====================================================================================
    // bind pbo and texture to render data now 

    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    //
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, flipped.cols, flipped.rows, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    gpuErrchk( cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(cuda_resource));
    gpuErrchk( cudaThreadSynchronize());

    //gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_inp));

    // ====================================================================================
    // map the texture coords to the vertex coords 

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad

    glEnd();

    glFlush();  // force rendering

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &pbo);
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that you do not need to map/unmap CUDA resources every time you draw in OpenGL to successfully do interop. Please refer to this example:
https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st