# OpenCV - copy CUDA device data into GPU Mat

Tags: opencv, cuda

Is there a way to directly copy previously allocated CUDA device data into an OpenCV GPU Mat? I would like to copy my data, previously initialized and filled by CUDA, into the OpenCV GPU mat. I would like to do so because I want solve a linear system of equations `Ax = B` by computing the inverse of the matrix `A` using OpenCV.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
float *dPtr; 
gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &dPtr, sizeof(float) * height * width));    
gpuErrchk( cudaMemset(dPtr, 0, sizeof(float) * height * width));

// modify dPtr in some way on the GPU 
modify_dPtr(); 

// copy previously allocated and modified dPtr into OpenCV GPU mat? 

// process GPU mat later - e.x. do a matrix inversion operation. 

// extract raw pointer from GPU mat
```

**EDIT:** 
The OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html#gpu-gpumat) provides a GPU `upload` function.

Can the device pointer just be passed into that function as a parameter? If not, is there no other way to do such a data transfer? I don't want to copy data back and forth between the host and device memory, do my computation on a normal OpenCV `Mat` container, and copy back the results; my application is real-time. I am assuming that since there is no `.at()` function for a `GPU Mat`, as in the normal OpenCV `Mat`, there is no way to access the element at a particular location in the matrix? Also, does an explicit matrix inversion operation exist for the GPU Mat? The documentation does not provide a GPU Mat `inv()` function.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote? I did my research in terms of asking the question, and my question is a valid question because my CUDA algorithm runs on the GPU. I want to interface the GPU module of OpenCV with my code; that way, I don't have to waste time copying to and fro from device to host memory. There is no clear cut interface to copy previously allocated CUDA device memory to an OpenCV GPU Mat container, which is in contrast to the general ease of use of the OpenCV Mat container with CUDA. I posted the question because other knowledgeable people might know an answer to my problem.

Comment: Whether OpenCV can do it or not (and I guess it can't), solving a set of linear equations by explicitly calculating the inverse is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512354/opengl-cuda-interop-image-not-displaying-in-window I think that goes the other way around openCV->CUDA but it may be a place to start.

Comment: @talonmies I agree, but he didn't ask for a good linear solver method. Just how to implement an inefficient one.

Comment: @talonmies Of course, if my matrix is singular and ill-conditioned, it's a bad way to solve the system. What I would do instead is solve it using the method of normal equations (A^T A)-1 A *B. My example was just for an illustration of what I want to do later.

Comment: Check the header for GpuMat. I think you will find a constructor which accepts a pre-existing pitced GPU allocation as data.

Comment: @talonmies You mean, encapsulate my pitched device data pointer as `typedef PtrStepSz<float> PtrStepSzf(rows, cols, d_Ptr, step);` ? I usually use `cudaMallocPitch` to estimate if I need a `step`.

Comment: No I mean instantiate a GpuMat with your pointer. Look in the header definition and you will find a constructor for that, I believe

Comment: @talonmies Good spot; upvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as talonmies posted in the comments, there is a constructor in the header of the GPU mat structure that allows the creation of a GPUMat header [pointing](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ab7210166f4bd124855b520b3dde28fb1) to my previously allocated CUDA device data. This is what I had used:

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat dst(height, width, CV_32F, d_Ptr);
```

There is no need to figure out the step size because the constructor automatically evaluates it, given the width and height of the image. 
Hopefully, when the support for OpenCV GPU functions becomes better, this post may be useful to someone.

**EDIT**

Another (probably) useful way is to utilize unified memory in CUDA. Pass the data into an OpenCV GPU and CPU mat, and continue operations from there.

Comment: Some comment : this constructor will not COPY your data. It will just create a GpuMat header for provided pointer, this GpuMat will not control the memory and will not free it in own destructor.

Comment: @jet47 Yes, the header just creates a GPUmat header pointing towards my data. Edited.